# How can I snip the tip off of a branch and put it somewhere else?

Tags: git

I was on a branch, `development`, and created a new branch, `feature1`. I coded feature 1, was happy, and decided to start work on feature 2. So I create a new branch `feature2` and make one commit. Oh no! Now my tree looks like this:

```
dev <- . <- . <- feature1 <- feature2
```

But `feature1` and `feature2` should both be branching off of `dev`, like this:

```
dev <- . <- . <- feature1
 ^
  \--- feature2
```

How can I achieve this result? I've been trying various forms of `git rebase` all night and can't get any joy.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the branches are named as shown, the rebase command should look as follows:

```
git rebase feature1 feature2 --onto dev
```

One syntax for `git rebase` is:

```
git rebase <upstream> <branch> --onto <newbase>
```

If `<branch>` was specified, Git first does `git checkout <branch>`. Afterwards, it calculates the base commit between `<upstream>` and the currently checked-out branch. In our case, `feature1` itself is the base commit, since its an ancestor of `feature2`. Next, Git will take all commits of the currently checked-out branch, up until that base commit, and apply them on `<newbase>`.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I fixed my issue using the method provided in the now deleted answer, so I can't test this now, but I didn't know about the --onto switch.

Comment: Oh, I thought I misunderstood your question based on the other answers provided. If that actually fixed your issue I'll undelete it

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
git checkout feature2
git rebase -i dev
# Delete all commits between 'dev' and feature2
```

Comment: Well, I certainly don't want to delete the code I wrote for `feature1`.

Comment: @JackM As long as the `feature1` branch is still around, all of the changes you made on that branch will still be there.  The commits from `dev` to `feature1` will only be removed from the `feature2` branch, which is the result you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by first creating the new branch:

```
git checkout -b feature2 dev
```

Followed by a cherry-pick:

```
git cherry-pick feature1
```

Then back to the old branch and remove the commit from there:

```
git checkout feature1
git reset @^ --hard
```